# Best way to remove seeds when making jam and still have it called jam

Tags: fruit, food-preservation, jam

When making jams and/or preserves using berries, sometimes you want the jam to be seedless (especially when using raspberries or blackberries).  I know often times people use a food mill or strain the fruit through a fine mess sieve, but would you get the same effect using a masticating juicer?  Or would that take too much of the fruit to still be considered jam?

Basically I'm asking if I use my masticating juicer to get the juice and pulp from blackberries or raspberries and can them, would it be considered seedless jam or is it now jelly?  And if it is now jelly, how using a masticating juicer makes it jelly when straining through a sieve still allows it to be jam?

Comment: Wouldn't a masticating juicer remove both the seeds **and** the pulp?

Comment: A regular juicer does, but a masticating juicer gives you everything that it possibly can.  The juice ends up being very thick.

Comment: FWIW, I tried using an auger juicer to get the juice from pomegranates to make jelly.  The seeds got pulverized and tainted the juice.  It took hours to strain them out.  If there is a way to extract the juice and pulp without grinding up the seeds as well, I would go with that method.

Answer (score 1):

I use a cheesecloth.  you can get the seeds out of the berries

Comment: I've done this too, but a jelly bag works better for all but the finest seeds.

Answer (score 0):

My hand crank grain mill worked great. I have a masticating steel hand crank wheatgrass juicer, but from past experience juicing fruits, the outlet at the end allows chunks to pass through, even with the outlet flow screwed down to maximum "pinching" the batch.

However the grain grinder ground up the seeds to flour size. It's a beautiful looking product. It does have a bit of a grainy texture. It will be interesting to see how it cooks down. It;s pretty much holding together like a jam already.

Glad to find the conversation. I think it's a rare one.

Answer (score -2):

I think that the best way to remove seeds when you prepare berries jelly is to use a sieve. But be aware that metallic sieves can alter the acidity of berries, so use a nylon sieve...